# How to retrieve RecyclerView position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, position

I am trying to get the position of items in my `RecyclerView`, mainly those that are at [0], [1], and [2] positions. The reason being is currently I am creating a leader board that will highlight the top 3 players with the highest score.

[image]

I have tried calling `getAdapterPosition()` but I guess I am using it incorrectly.

```
if(holder.getAdapterPosition() == 0)
{
    Glide.with(holder.firstPlace.getContext())
            .load(model.getUrl())
            .into(holder.firstPlace);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction. Thank you.

Edit 1:

**My UserAdapter**

```
public class UserAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<UserModel, UserAdapter.UserViewHolder> {

public UserAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<UserModel> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserModel model) {

    holder.username.setText(model.getFullName());
    holder.email.setText(model.getEmail());
    holder.score.setText(model.getScore()+"");
    holder.rank.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));


    Glide.with(holder.userImage.getContext())
            .load(model.getUrl())
            .into(holder.userImage);


    //error here
//        if(holder.getAdapterPosition() == 0)
//        {
//            Glide.with(holder.firstPlace.getContext())
//                    .load(model.getUrl())
//                    .into(holder.firstPlace);
//        }

}


@NonNull
@Override
public UserAdapter.UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_leaderboard_single, parent, false);
    return new UserViewHolder(view);
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CircleImageView userImage;
    TextView username;
    TextView email;
    TextView score;
    TextView rank;

    CircleImageView firstPlace;
    CircleImageView secondPlace;
    CircleImageView thirdPlace;

    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_username);
        email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_email);
        score = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_score);
        rank = itemView.findViewById(R.id.leaderboard_position);

        firstPlace = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place1stProfile);
        secondPlace = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place2ndProfile);
        thirdPlace = itemView.findViewById(R.id.place3rdProfile);
    }
}
```

**list_leaderboard_single.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#EFCDB4">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#FFE5C6"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/leaderboard_position"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="##"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_image"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leaderboard_position"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_username"
        android:layout_width="173dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Email"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_username"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Score"
        android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#000"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PTS"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_blood_drop"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_leaderboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Leaderboard"
android:background="#790604">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="L E A D E R B O A R D"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:minHeight="150dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        >

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/place2ndProfile"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_below="@id/place2ndProfile"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="2ND"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/place1stProfile"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
                android:layout_below="@id/place1stProfile"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="1ST"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/place3rdProfile"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
                android:layout_below="@id/place3rdProfile"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="3RD"/>
        </RelativeLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/leaderboard_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Could you post your `Adapter` code for the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: will do @IvanGarza

Comment: done! you should be able to see it after a quick refresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `holder.getAdapterPosition` only within the `ViewHolder`; instead you can simply use the parameter `position` passed in `onBindViewHolder()`.

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.UserViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull UserModel model) {
    // .....
    if(position == 0)
    {
        Glide.with(holder.firstPlace.getContext())
                .load(model.getUrl())
                .into(holder.firstPlace);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this, @Zain. it gave me an error and crashes the application

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView.getContext()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.loginregisterfire.Adapter.UserAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UserAdapter.java:49)`

Comment: can you share the `R.layout.list_leaderboard_single` layout or can you check specifically that the `CircleImageView` `Ids` in the layout are matched with the `ViewHolder` class

Comment: Done! but for the highlights of first, second, and third place, it was defined in the MainActivity.xml. Above the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: good job! do you still encounter any errors?

Comment: yes the same one as above. Is it because it was defined outside of `R.layout.list_leaderboard_single` since only that xml is being inflated.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to access views in the `activity_main.xml` within the adapter, and you can't do that because the adapter can access only views from its row list item layout which is `list_leaderboard_single` .. If you really want to access those views, you need to create a listener interface between the activity and adapter, implement it in the activity, and then pass data using its callback within the adapter.. please let me know if anything isn't clear

Comment: ohhh make sense! but sounds very complicated to do..

Comment: yeah, but it gets things separated for the sake of single responsibility rule.. give it a try and let me know if you need some help

Comment: I have no clue where to even start, I appreciate any help I can get. I haven't dabble with listener interface before.

Comment: or is there any better alternative for me to highlights the top 3 players?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226428/discussion-between-zain-and-scrin).